# Firebase iOS Phone Login - Recaptcha Not Working on Simulator & Device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Firestore for iOS. I started noticing that the recaptcha on the simulator was not coming up.  Instead it would crash at the app delegate method - didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError - with the error "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator"

Also, if I turn off notifications and background refresh on my device, it still sends the SMS, which the docs say should trigger the recaptcha.

I do not have the method swizzling disabled and I have the Reversed Client ID in the URL types. The reCaptcha used to work at some point on the simulator too. I always had trouble verifying it to work on the device.

UPDATE AGAIN - I installed Xcode 10 and it works on simulator now.  But still not working on a device with background refresh turned off and I reinstalled the app. It instead sends an SMS and SKIPS the recaptcha after calling - PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber.  It's supposed to send the SMS after the recaptcha, so why does it do that even though there's no reCaptcha?  I do have background fetch turned on, but if the background refresh is off, the silent notification should not work, right? However it calls a method I use for cloud messaging - didReceiveRegistrationToken - with the fcmToken. Is the phone auth using this fcmToken to send the SMS? And I guess this method does not rely on silent notification. I'm was getting ready to release my first app and worry that Apple could reject if it's some how using APNS in some way, as there's a guideline that an app cannot depend on APNS.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Here's a screenshot of the simulator error.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?